# Splitting a value using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="initial_data.dept_bp" ng-change="get_sod()" class="form-control">
  <option ng-repeat="s in sod_list" ng-value="s.dept" >{{s.dept_name}}__{{s.bp_name}}</option>
</select>
```

I am passing the ng-model value into my ngcontroller/script
`var str = $scope.initial_data.dept_bp`. But the value inside is a combination of two DB columns separated by "__". How can I split this value into 2 different variables? like those before __ is one variable and after __ is another variable irregardless of length of the ng-model value. Thanks in advance

Comment: can't you use  str.split('__')  , it will return an array of two splitted strings?

Comment: can i use something like `var newstr = str.split('__',1)[0];`

Comment: does this have anything to do with AngularJS? Do you just want to split the string with javascript or do you want to do it in the angular template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have a string like this `var str = "value1__value2";` which it sounds like you do you can use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to break the string into an array of values. So if we did `result = str.split("__");` the `result` would be `["value1", "value2"]`. To assign these to two separate variables like you've asked you could then do:

```
var firstVariable = result[0];
var secondVariable = result[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option ng-repeat="s in sod_list" ng-value="s.dept" >{{s.dept_name + "__" + s.bp_name}}</option>
```